# Batch file input not working correctly when in if block

Tags: batch-file

When using `set /p` inside this if block. The variable `input` is not set to the input value. It is set only on second invocation of the script (as if it was set only after `echo %input%` line).

```
 if "%1"=="" (
        echo "You have to specify the name of the file."
        set /p input=File name: 
        echo %input%
        pause

 ) else (
        ...
 )
```

What can I do to have variable `input` set to values which was actually entered?

Answer (score 3):

you don't need `delayed expansion` here. Example:

```
 if "%1"=="" (
        echo "You have to specify the name of the file."
        set /p input=File name: 
        call echo %%input%%
        pause

 ) else (
        ...
 )
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use delayed expansion.

In the Batch language, inside a FOR or a IF, the variables are "expanded" before and not during command execution. ( expanded = the variable is remplaced by its value )

For example,  the following IF test

```
IF condition (
foo
bar
)
```

is interpreted as `if condition foo & bar`

So if a variable is set in `foo` and this same variable is used in bar, it's the previous value of the variable ( the one before entering the loop ) that is used in `bar`.

It's kinda disturbing but that how Batch works... 
So ithe `set` is working correctly, it's just a special way of working.

You must write `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` at the beginning of your code and the variable whose expansion should be delayed must be surrounded by `!` instead of `%`.

So `echo %input%` become `echo !input!`

Comment: True, I agree with Julien.  If you enable delayed expansion then the SET /P will work inside a for block.

Comment: @djangofan - Actually, SET /P works regardless. It is only the display of the stored value that requires delayed expansion.

Comment: The `if condition foo && bar` should be written as `if condition foo & bar`. As originally written with `&&`, `bar` will only execute if `foo` was successfull. `||` is the conditional operator for failure. The simple command concatenation operator is a single `&`.